# Cannot replace digit with new line in sed but can be replace in sublime

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I have a document with multiple lines. I want to replace the newline characters in the lines that don't end with numbers

Suppose the document is:

```
line1
line2
line
line
line
line4
```

I want to get

```
line1
line2
linelinelineline4
```

I can do this in sublime by replacing `([^\d])(\n)` by `\1`. While trying this in sed it's not working. Can someone help me what's wrong in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't support `\d`, you can use `[0-9]` instead. Also, by default, `sed` works line by line and you cannot manipulate the `\n` character at end of line. There are ways to overcome this, but I wouldn't suggest to use `sed` for this task.

```
$ awk '{ORS = /[0-9]$/ ? RS : ""} 1' ip.txt
line1
line2
linelinelineline4
```

- `ORS` is output record separator
- `/[0-9]$/` check if input line ends with a digit

  - if so, use `RS` as `ORS` (which is `\n` by default)
  - else, use empty string
- `1` is an `awk` idiom as a shortcut to print contents of `$0` (input record)

`perl` allows to manipulate newline character as it isn't removed and added back like `sed` or `awk`

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)\n//' ip.txt
line1
line2
linelinelineline4
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
sed '/[^[:digit:]]$/{   ;# if current line ends with non-number
:l                      ;# define a label "l"
N                       ;# read the next line and append to the pattern space
s/\n//                  ;# remove the newline
/[[:digit:]]$/b         ;# if the appended line ends with number, exit the loop
bl                      ;# jump to label "l" and repeat
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/[^0-9]\n/s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Append the next line and if the first line does not end in a digit, remove the newline and repeat. Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.